# scanf not to exceed buffer overrun

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I have a buffer and I don't want the user to enter more characters than the buffer can hold (to avoid a buffer overrun).

I am using `scanf` and have done like this:

```
char buffer[30] = {'\0'};
scanf("%30s", buffer);
```

However, I know I am protected if the user enters more than 30. However, if the user enters more than 30, will the buffer be null terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf()` with a "%s" conversion specifier adds a terminating null character to the buffer.

**But**, you're asking for 30 characters, which really means 31 and only have space for 30. You should use a maximum field width of 29.

```
char buffer[30] = {'\0'};
scanf("%29s", buffer);
```

Also note that the conversion specifier `"%c"` works pretty much like `"%s"`, but does not add the terminating null character and does not discard space from the input. Depending on what you expect, it might be better than using "%s".

```
char buffer[30] = {'\0'};
scanf("%29c", buffer);
buffer[29] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `scanf` manual:

> **s**         Matches a sequence of
>   non-white-space characters; the next
>   pointer
>              must be a pointer to char, and the array must be large enough to
>              accept all the sequence and the terminating NUL character.  The
>              input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width,
>              whichever occurs first.

You are invoking UB. Try:

```
#define str(x) #x
#define xstr(s) str(x)
#define BUFSIZE 30

char buffer[ BUFSIZE + 1 ];
scanf("%" xstr(BUFSIZE) "s", buf);
```

To ignore anything beyond `BUFSIZE` characters suppress assignment:

```
scanf("%" xstr(BUFSIZE) "s%*", buf);
```

You should also check if the user has entered return/newline and terminate `scanf` if he has:

```
scanf("%" xstr(BUFSIZE) "[^\n]s%[^\n]*", buf);
```

and it is good practice to check for return values, so:

```
int rc = scanf("%" xstr(BUFSIZE) "[^\n]s%[^\n]*", buf);
```

and finally, check if the there's anything left (such as the newline, and consume it):

```
if (!feof(stdin))
    getchar();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have a buffer overrun because you haven't allowed for the terminating NUL character. Declare your buffer like this:

```
char buffer[31];
```

and you will be fine.