# out put the value from structure

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct classifier
{
    char src_address[15];
    char dst_address[15];
    int src_port;
    int  dst_port;
};

main()
{
    int i;
    struct classifier clsf[4];
    struct classifier *ptr;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        ptr = & clsf[i];
        scanf("%s",ptr[i].src_address);
        scanf("%s",ptr[i].dst_address);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i].src_port);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i].dst_port);
        display(ptr[i]);
    }
}

void display(struct classifier ptr)
{
    printf("\n%s", ptr.src_address );
    printf("\n%s", ptr.dst_address );
    printf("\n%d", ptr.src_port);
    printf("\n%d", ptr.dst_port );
}
```

the o/p that i get is like this

```
this is i/p

123.123.123.123 
213.234.234.124
3244
1342

o/p
123.123.123.123213.234.234.124
213.234.234.124
3244
1342
```

why is that first value repeating. what is wrong in the code

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 6):

Because you write too much data into your strings.

```
char src_address[15];
```

is 15 chars long, including the terminating 0 character, thus you must not put more than 14 characters into it. However, `123.123.123.123` is 15 chars.

Since the two fields `src_address` and `dst_address` happen to be stored in consecutive memory blocks, the value written into the latter follows immediately - without a separating 0 byte - the former. Thus `printf` cannot but print both when you intend to print the former.

You should reserve enough space in your char arrays to incorporate the terminating 0 value (and explicitly ensure that it really is put there!). In general, in real life apps you should [defend yourself against buffer overruns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721073/scanf-not-to-exceed-buffer-overrun) [caused by too long input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).